# My loop only prints out one object to my tableview. I´m using Java

Tags: java, loops

```
private void displayGroupsInRanking() {


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 

    {

        RankingANames.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(groupModel.getListA().get(i).getName()));
        System.out.println(RankingANames);

    }
        RankingBNames.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(groupModel.getListB()));
        RankingCNames.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(groupModel.getListC()));
        RankingDNames.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(groupModel.getListD()));


}
```

I´m trying to, to get a specific attribute from an arraylist into a new arraylist. This works fine, but the listview only shows one object?
[The output[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMeH7.png)

[the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnOxA.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Thanks. I´m new to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 3):

I'll not rewrite code from your screen to show you the right way to do this but I can tell you what is wrong here.

On every iteration you are creating new collection with exactly one item and then you are using it as items list for table.
That's clearly wrong.

To solve it, you have to first prepare full list of items and then pass it to `setItems` method.

Comment: All the different ranking list takes a list, with 4 teams. then I should have a full list. Or maybe I misunderstood you answer.
and thanks for the help :)
Elon Than

Comment: @EdwinMhoySilva read your code carefully. Each iteration of your `for` loop resets rows in your table and adds current item to it. You should call `setItems` only once per table, not per row.

Comment: I understand now. Then I need to make a need variable, all my items, and then use the variable and the method getNames? :)